# How to load a javascript function once on ajax website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a javascript function that needs to be in content element, and not on header, because of dynamic ajax reload which reloads the main content and not the header.

I'd like to load this javascript function only once per session. I mean that when the user clicks on "page 1", the page loads this specific function, and when he clicks on page 2, then clicks again on "page 1", the javascript function doesn't reload itself.

Is there a way to do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Create an object that tracks if the page has been loaded or not

```
var isLoaded = {
   page1: false,
   page2: false
};

// click...
if (isLoaded.page1) {
   $('#page1').show();
} else {
  $.get('/page1.html', function(html) {
      $('#page1').append(html).show();
      isLoaded.page1 = true;
  });
}
```

Comment: In fact, here is my javascript function:

<script type="text/javascript">$(function() {
YAHOO.MediaPlayer.addTracks(document.getElementById("ajazload"),1,false)});</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

How can I prevent it to reload at every ajax page load ? I just want this function loads at the first load of the page.